# Different headheight for first page

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

I'm writing a document using the Koma-Script class `scrartcl` (3.09a).

I want to have a header and a footer on every page, but the header of the first page should be different from the others.

So using `\newpagestyle` from the `scrpage2` package I define two page styles, `MyFirstPageStyle` and `MyPageStyle`, and I use them like this:

```
\pagestyle{MyPageStyle}
\thispagestyle{MyFirstPageStyle}
```

Since the header of the first page is quite big, it overlaps with the content of the first page. I could fix this by passing `[headinclude=true, headheight=2cm]` as class options. But this also affects the headers of all other pages, where the header is just one line in height.

So my question is how can I set `headheight` for the first page only, without affecting the other pages?

To make more clear how it should look in the end: The white space between the top of the header and the top of the page should be the same for all pages. But the header of the first page is larger, so the content of the first page should move down a little bit.

Full minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline]{scrpage2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\newpagestyle{MyTitlePageStyle}
{
  {}
  {}
  {
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth-5.5cm}
      \normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries
      DigSig1 Praktikum 1 - Lösungen \\
      Signalabtastung / Zeitdiskretisierung
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{5cm}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{HSR}
    \end{minipage}
  }
}
{
  {}
  {}
  {
    \normalfont
    HRO, \today
    \hfill
    \pagemark{}/\pageref{LastPage}
  }
}

\newpagestyle{MyPageStyle}
{
  {}
  {}
  {
    \normalfont
    DigSig1 Praktikum 1 - Lösungen
    \hfill
    Signalabtastung / Zeitdiskretisierung
  }
}
{
  {}
  {}
  {
    \normalfont
    HRO, \today
    \hfill
    \pagemark{}/\pageref{LastPage}
  }
}

\pagestyle{MyPageStyle}
\thispagestyle{MyTitlePageStyle}

\begin{document}

content

\end{document}
```

With the code provided above, the header of the first page overlaps with the content of the first page. When I use

```
\documentclass[headinclude=true, headheight=2cm]{scrartcl}
```

instead, it looks fine for the first page, but it also increases the white space above the headers of the following pages, which I don't want.

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example. You can influence options in the document body with the command `\KOMAoptions`.

Comment: This MWE does not even compile...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write

```
\AtBeginDocument{\vspace*{2\baselineskip}}
```

or, simply

```
\begin{document}
\vspace*{2\baselineskip}
```

The first form is more suitable if you're preparing a personalized `.sty` file. Change the `2` into what is best for you.

Comment: I like the solution with `AtBeginDocument` the most because this way I can handle the page setup completely in the preamble. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. But I a similar problem with a twocolumn document. In this case, that command only adds space to the first column. Is there a solution that moves down both columns?

Answer (score 3):

You can customize options within the document using `\KOMAoption` or `\KOMAoptions`. If you change the layout parameters, `\recalctypearea` recalculates the layout for you.

Example:

```
\KOMAoptions{headheight=3cm,headinclude=true}
\recalctypearea
content of first page
\KOMAoptions{headheight=1.25\baselineskip,headinclude=false}
\recalctypearea
\clearpage
further content
```

Note that you might have to do further adjustments because of the different values of headinclude. If necessary, you can make further adjustments to the textbody using `\areaset`.

Or consider using `headinclude=true` consistently in the document.

Comment: Can this be put inside custom page style or somehow automated? Or does one have to figure out where exactly the first page ends to call `\recalctypearea` second time?