# Separate page geometry for some pages (without using \newpage)

Tags: header-footer, margins, geometry

I have different document classes with separate page geometry for some pages. Often the first page has a bigger header or footer.

The [geometry](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package allows to store different geometries with `\savegeometry` and load them with `\loadgeometry`. This works well if the position of the geometry change is known in advance and defined through `\newpage`.

If the position of the geometry change in form of `\newpage` is not specified explicitly but should be after a certain page this is not straight forward like in the following example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%
% Select approach
%
% 1: Separate page geometry for first page
% 2: Same page geometry for all pages but adjusted header, \vspace at document begin and \enlargethispage for first page
% 3: No \loadgeometry, \afterpage or other geometry modifications
\newcounter{approach}
\setcounter{approach}{1}
%
% Select test case
%
% 1: Two sections and text [passed with approach 1 and 2]
% 2: One section and text [failed with approach 1 but passed with approach 2]
% 3: One section and itemize (split over two pages) surrounded by text [failed with approach 1 but passed with approach 2]
% And probably many other test cases that will fail with approach 1...
% Approach results per definition in a not desired result
\newcounter{testcase}
\setcounter{testcase}{1}
%
% Page geometry
%
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
%
\newgeometry{margin=20mm, headheight=\baselineskip, footskip=2\baselineskip, includehead, includefoot}
\savegeometry{standard}
%
\ifnum\value{approach}=1
    \newgeometry{margin=20mm, headheight=4\baselineskip, footskip=4\baselineskip, includehead, includefoot}
    \savegeometry{title}
\fi
%
\loadgeometry{standard}
\setlength{\footheight}{\baselineskip}
%
% Page styles
%
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
%
\newcommand*{\headerstandard}{Document (Approach \arabic{approach}, Test case \arabic{testcase}) \hfill Date}
\newcommand*{\headertitle}{\headerstandard\\ Item\\ Item\\ Item}
%
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{}
\newcommand*{\footerstandard}{Id \hfill Page \pagemark}
\newcommand*{\footertitle}{Info\\ Info\\ \footerstandard}
%
\defpagestyle{standard}{%
    {}{}{\headerstandard}%
}{%
    {}{}{\smash{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\footerstandard}}}%
}
\ifnum\ifnum\value{approach}=1 1\else\ifnum\value{approach}=3 1\else 0\fi\fi=1% \value{approach}=1 or \value{approach}=3
    \defpagestyle{title}{%
        {}{}{\headertitle}%
    }{%
        {}{}{\smash{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\footertitle}}}%
    }
\fi
\ifnum\value{approach}=2
    \defpagestyle{title}{%
        {}{}{\smash{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\headertitle}}}%
    }{%
        {}{}{\smash{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\footertitle}}}%
    }
\fi
\pagestyle{standard}
%
% Title page
%
\ifnum\value{approach}=1
    \usepackage{afterpage}
    %
    \renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
        \thispagestyle{title}%
        \loadgeometry{title}%
        % ...
        \afterpage{\aftergroup\restoregeometry}%
    }
\fi
\ifnum\value{approach}=2
    \renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
        \thispagestyle{title}%
        \vspace*{3\baselineskip}% Hack to simulate bigger head height
        \vspace{-\parskip}%
        \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
        \vspace{-1.535\baselineskip}% Hack two remove vertical space inserted if followed by section
        % ...
        \enlargethispage{-3\baselineskip}% Hack has not exact the same result as in approach 1
    }
\fi
\ifnum\value{approach}=3
    \renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
        \thispagestyle{title}%
        % ...
    }
\fi
%
\AtBeginDocument{\maketitle}
%
% Document with test cases
%
\begin{document}
\ifnum\value{testcase}=1
    \section{Section}%
    \blindtext[6]%
    \section{Section}%
    \blindtext[3]%
\fi
\ifnum\value{testcase}=2
    \section{Section}%
    \blindtext[6]%
\fi
\ifnum\value{testcase}=3
    \section{Section}%
    \blindtext[5]%
    \blinditemize[7]%
    \blindtext[5]%
\fi
\end{document}
```

I found and tried one approach (called **approach 1** in the example) using `\afterpage` from the [afterpage](https://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) package:

- [How to set page geometry for a single page only?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78278/how-to-set-page-geometry-for-a-single-page-only)

In this approach I used a separate page geometry for the first page but it fails in the last two of the three provided test cases. See the the not changed header height and in test case 3 also the overfull `\vbox` at the bottom on page two:

1. [image] [image] 2. [image] [image] 3. [image] [image]

As an alternative I tried a second approach (called **approach 2** in the example) with following references:

- [Different headheight for first page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30232/different-headheight-for-first-page)
- [Unwanted extra space before \vspace* at top of page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247513/unwanted-extra-space-before-vspace-at-top-of-page)
- [Newgeometry and afterpage don't adjust the geometry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267067/newgeometry-and-afterpage-dont-adjust-the-geometry)

Thereby I kept the same page geometry for all pages but adjusted the header, added `\vspace` at page begin and `\enlargethispage` for the first page. This approach passes all test cases but comes with some problems in the code realization. I have to add one positive `\vspace` to respect the bigger head height and one negative `\vspace` to remove the vertical space that is added from the following section. Also the `\enlargethispage` results in a different text height as in approach 1:

1. [image] [image] 2. [image] [image] 3. [image] [image]

Finally my questions are:

1. Is it possible to make approach 1 with `\afterpage` working reliable?
2. Is it in addition possible to compute the header and footer height automatically? In the example I defined them manually for one special case although it should work automatically for other cases.

Thank you very much for your help.

**Update:**

According to the comment from @David Carlisle I have added a third appraoch (called **approach 3** in the updated example) coming from approach 1 with no `\loadgeometry`, `\afterpage` or other geometry modifications. But this approach results per definition in a not desired result. Thereby the text body height is constant and the header on the first page with a bigger height is not aligned at the top with the header on the second page. The footer also with a bigger height on the first page is aligned at the bottom with the footer on the second page but has a collision with the text body:

1. [image] [image]

I also have to say that approach 2 comes also with no geometry changes but with some `\vspace` hacks.

Comment: it is not possible to change the horizontal width without forcing a page break so commands such as `\newgeometry` are usually restricted to a forced page break, you say the position of the change of size isn't known in advance but you seem to only use a different size in `\maketitle` on the first page?

Comment: You are right. The position of the change of size (in the example after the first page) is known, but a \newpage is not specified explicitly. So I used `\afterpage`. I changed the explanation in the question.

Comment: If this is about customizing the title exclusively, the answer is different.

Comment: @Michael but that is doing things backwards, you don't need to do anything at the page break, set up the main document page style then use `\thispagestyle` for the title-page, no need for afterpage or newgeometries etc,

Comment: @David Carlisle I have updated the question according to your comment.

Comment: For KOMA, you can change the margins (left/right) easily, but top/bottom margins must be changed before the new page starts. You might look at the flowfram package.

Comment: Do you look for 4 th approach (approach 1 modified) ?

Comment: @touhami Yes. I want to use approach 1 with modifications so that the change of geometry is working in general, not just for a few cases. But why is a change of geometry for TeX/LaTeX so complicated?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mwe}
\newcounter{testcase}
\setcounter{testcase}{3}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter 
\def\Gmt@restore{}
\apptocmd\Gm@savelength{%
  \g@addto@macro\Gmt@restore{\global\expandafter\noexpand\expandafter\csname
  #1\endcsname\expandafter=\expandafter\the\csname #1\endcsname\relax}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@outputpage}{\global \@colht \textheight}{\Gmt@restore@pkg \global \@colht \textheight}{}{} 
\makeatother

\newgeometry{margin=20mm, headheight=\baselineskip, footskip=2\baselineskip, includehead, includefoot}
\savegeometry{standard}

\makeatletter 
\edef\Gmt@restore@pkg{\Gmt@restore
 \global\expandafter\let\expandafter\noexpand\expandafter\Gmt@restore@pkg\noexpand\empty}%
\makeatother

\newgeometry{margin=20mm, headheight=4\baselineskip, footskip=4\baselineskip, includehead, includefoot}
\savegeometry{title}

\loadgeometry{standard}

\setlength{\footheight}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\newcommand*{\headerstandard}{Document (Approach 1, Test case 2) \hfill Date}
\newcommand*{\headertitle}{\headerstandard\\ Item\\ Item\\ Item}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{}
\newcommand*{\footerstandard}{Id \hfill Page \pagemark}
\newcommand*{\footertitle}{Info\\ Info\\ \footerstandard}
\defpagestyle{standard}{%
    {}{}{\headerstandard}%
}{%
    {}{}{\smash{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\footerstandard}}}%
}
\defpagestyle{title}{%
        {}{}{\headertitle}%
    }{%
        {}{}{\smash{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\footertitle}}}%
    }
\pagestyle{standard}

\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
    \thispagestyle{title}%
    \loadgeometry{title}%%
}
\AtBeginDocument{\maketitle}
\begin{document}
\ifnum\value{testcase}=1
    \section{Section}%
    \blindtext[6]%
    \section{Section}%
    \blindtext[3]%
\fi
\ifnum\value{testcase}=2
    \section{Section}%
    \blindtext[6]%
\fi
\ifnum\value{testcase}=3
    \section{Section}%
    \blindtext[5]%
    \blinditemize[7]%
    \blindtext[5]%
\fi  
\end{document}
```